# How to render a subroute and trigger react router parents loader?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have this router:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  [
    {
      path: '/',
      element: <Navigate to={'/dashboards'}/>
    },
    {
      path: '/dashboards',
      element: <Dashboards/>,
      loader: () => store.dispatch(retrieveWarehouses()),
      children: [
        {
          path: ':warehouse',
          element: <Dashboard/>,
          loader: ({ params }) => store.dispatch(monitorWarehouse(params.warehouse))
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
)
```

Defined as is, the `<Dashboard/>` component is not rendered, only its parent dashboard list (`Dashboards`, notice the plural). The loader of the child `Dashboard` is still triggered though.

If I don't use a nested route:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  [
    {
      path: '/',
      element: <Navigate to={'/dashboards'}/>
    },
    {
      path: '/dashboards',
      element: <Dashboards/>,
      loader: () => store.dispatch(retrieveWarehouses()),
    },
    {
      path: '/dashboards/:warehouse',
      element: <Dashboard/>,
      loader: ({ params }) => store.dispatch(monitorWarehouse(params.warehouse))
    }
  ]
)
```

The child component `Dashboard` is rendered properly, but the loader of the parent is not triggered.

**Here are the components:**

**Dashboards**

```
const Dashboards: React.FC<any> = () => {
  const {
    warehouses,
    loading
  } = useAppSelector(selectWarehouseListState)

  if (loading) {
    return (
      <div className={'warehouse-list'}>
        <h1>Select warehouse</h1>
        <Spinner/>
      </div>
    )
  }

  return (
    <div className={'warehouse-list'}>
      <h1>Select warehouse</h1>
      {
        warehouses.map((wh: Warehouse) => (
          <NavLink to={`/dashboards/${wh.name}`} key={wh.name}>
            <div className={'selectable-warehouse container'}>
              {wh.name}
            </div>
          </NavLink>
        ))
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

**Dashboard**

```
const Dashboard: React.FC<any> = () => {
  const { loading } = useAppSelector(selectWarehouseState)
  const { warehouse } = useParams()
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch()

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      dispatch(stopMonitorWarehouse(warehouse))
    }
  }, [dispatch])

  if (loading) {
    return (
      <div className={'dashboard loading shrinkable'}>
        <div className={'header'}>
          <NavLink to={'/dashboards'} className={'nav-back'}>
            <ArrowBack/>
          </NavLink>
          <div className={'selected-warehouse-name'}>{warehouse}</div>
        </div>
        <div className={'status connecting'}>status: connecting</div>
        <Spinner/>
      </div>
    )
  }

  return (
    <div className={'dashboard active shrinkable'}>
      <div className={'header'}>
        <NavLink to={'/dashboards'} className={'nav-back'}>
          <ArrowBack/>
        </NavLink>
        <div className={'selected-warehouse-name'}>{warehouse}</div>
      </div>
      <div className={'status connected'}>status: connected</div>
      <div className={'logs-metrics'}>
        <Logs/>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

How can I access `/dashboards/foo` and trigger both loaders ?

Comment: Can you share the routed components you are trying to render, specifically the `Dashboards` component? Is it rendering an `Outlet` for its nested routes to be rendered to?

Comment: Hmm no and you probably pinpointed the problem. How should I use it ?

Comment: Render `Outlet` above, or below, the warehouse links I suppose. Need an example?

Comment: I think I see the idea, however in my usecase I don't want both components to be rendered, the latter should take precedence of the other. I still believe I need the outlet but I'm unsure how to use it for my need. I'll dig some more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `Dashboards` component is rendered as a layout route then it necessarily should render an `Outlet` for its nested routes to render their content into.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const Dashboards: React.FC<any> = () => {
  const {
    warehouses,
    loading
  } = useAppSelector(selectWarehouseListState)

  return (
    <div className={'warehouse-list'}>
      <h1>Select warehouse</h1>
      {loading ? (
        <Spinner />
      ) : (
        <>
          {warehouses.map((wh: Warehouse) => (
            <NavLink to={`/dashboards/${wh.name}`} key={wh.name}>
              <div className={'selectable-warehouse container'}>
                {wh.name}
              </div>
            </NavLink>
          ))}
          <Outlet />
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

> However in my use case I don't want both components to be rendered, the
> latter should take precedence of the other.

If I understand this part you want the `Dashboards` and `Dashboard` components rendered independently, but the `Dashboards`'s loader function to still be called *even while* on a nested route. For this you'll render `Dashboards` as a nested index route where the loader function is on the parent layout route.

Example:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  [
    {
      path: '/',
      element: <Navigate to="/dashboards" />
    },
    {
      path: '/dashboards',
      loader: () => store.dispatch(retrieveWarehouses()),
      children: [
        {
          index: true,
          element: <Dashboards />,
        },
        {
          path: ':warehouse',
          element: <Dashboard />,
          loader: ({ params }) => {
            store.dispatch(monitorWarehouse(params.warehouse));
          },
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
);
```

The `"/dashboards"` route will render an `Outlet` by default when no `element` is specified, and the `Dashboards` component will be rendered when the parent route is matched. No changes to the `Dashboards` component would be required.